# PHP - Sphinx Search Integration Issues

Tags: php

I have installed sphinx.0.9.9 in my LINUX server, and tested the application in terminal. It is working, when i tried to use the sphinxapi.php, I'm getting the following issue. "Query failed: connection to localhost:9312 failed (errno=111, msg=Connection refused). ". Can anybody help me to figure out this issue

Thanks in advance.
Raja

Answer (score 1):

check your sphinx daemon "searchd" service status,may be you forgot start it ,or listen on others port.